# How do I apply my Random Forest classifier to an unlabelled dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

Using sklearn, I have just finished training, tuning hyperparameters and testing a Random Forest Multiclass Classifier using RandomizedSearchCV. I have obtained the best parameters, best score and so on. This was all done with a labelled dataset. Now I want to apply this classifier onto an unlabelled dataset (meaning there are only the features and no classes) to make class/label predictions.

How do I go about doing this?

I haven't tried anything yet because I am stuck.

Comment: PLease post your code

Comment: @gtomer just edited it!

Comment: @johndo I see you've edited the answer again to remove code. I didn't downvote, but that's probably why you have these downvotes now. Please note my answer was based on the code available in [this version of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74613826/2).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer is based on the following version of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74613826/2

You can use the `forest_search.predict(X_test)` method, which will use the [best parameters found in search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.predict).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try to go to unsupervised learning direction and try one of the clustering methods (for example, `KMeans`).

Here is the example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit_predict(X)
print(kmeans)
```

Cool thing about this approach, that you compare new labels, received after clusting with the results of your RandomForest previous model